# Is the sum of residuals times a regressor equal to zero?

Tags: statistics, regression, least-squares, estimation, linear-regression

Suppose I am approximating the following system using ordinary least squares regression

$$y = p_0 + p_1 x_1 + p_2 x_2 + ... p_M x_M = \xi P$$

I know that a property of the least squares estimator is that the sum of the residuals, $r_i = \hat{y}_i - y_i$, is equal to zero. However, what I am finding is that the sum of the residuals multiplied by one of the regressors, $\xi_m \in (\mathbf{1}, x_1, x_2, ..., x_M)$, is also equal to zero. I have found this to be true in all cases in simulation, but I am not sure how to prove it.

$$\sum_{i=0}^{N} r_i \xi_m = 0$$

Intuitively it makes sense to me. For example, another property is that the residuals are normally distributed. The normal distribution is a continuous, even function. Let's denote it $f_N(x)$. Then, the integral $\int f_N(x)x = 0$ because you are integrating a (now) odd function over a symmetric interval. Thus $\Delta x\sum f_N(x) x  =0$

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a regression model

$$y_i=X_i'\beta+\epsilon_i$$

The least squares problem is to minimize

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_i-X_i'\beta)^2$$

The first order condition for the optimal coefficient vector $\hat{\beta}$  is

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}2(y_i-X_i'\hat{\beta})X_i=0$$

or

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\epsilon_iX_i=0$$

which says that the sample autocovariance between the residual and each regressor is zero.

Answer (score 0):

The property is true because, in linear regression, you are projecting (orthogonally) your target vector onto the subspace generated by the features (columns of the design matrix) and solving an approximate system
$$
Xw=\tilde y
$$
where $\tilde y$ is the projection of $y$ onto the above mentioned subspace. Then the difference $y-\tilde y$ is orthogonal to the subspace, so it is orthogonal to each of the feature columns and, therefore, the dot products are equal to zero.